# How to get Event from Application in GStreamer?

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer

I send an event to a pipeline:

```
GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new();
GstEvent*  event = gst_event_new_eos();
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, event);
```

How to **pipeline** get (handle) **eos event** which send. Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen to GstMessage on GstBus (gst_pipeline_get_bus). There is an GST_MESSAGE_EOS that will be emitted when the streaming reached the end.

Comment: yes, i have gotten bus from a pipeline, and handle messages: GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(pipeline); gst_bus_add_watch(bus, (G_CALLBACK)bus_callback, (G_MAINLOOP)loop)); and in callback function, i have listened GST_MESSAGE_EOS, but nothing happen. Please help me, thank

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to your sources (link to repo or pastebin). You're missing something else. Try looking at the debug log (GST_DEBUG="*:4" ./your-app (e.g. using gst-debug-viewer from freedesktop.org).

Answer (score 0):

If you just write a application, you should not care the event handle process, because the plug-in or base element library will do the `gst_pad_set_event_function()` operation, and the event handle function will handle the event you sent(GST_EVENT_EOS or others).

In the `GStreamer` source code, you can see that an event send to the element(pipeline) will push(by calling the `gst_pad_push_event()`) to a pad(src or sink, depending on `GST_EVENT_IS_DOWNSTREAM(event)`'s return value), then the pad judge if the event is its, if not, send if to the peer pad.

Is this helpful to u?

Comment: yeah, i need to handle EOS event, because that is requirement of my professor. Imaging application will send to you packets, you must decode packet, push decoded data to queue, then display them in real time (of course, must be synchronized). So i need notify EOS event to pipeline when i have send last packet. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: I think people will be able to help you more effectively if you rather tell what you want to do and ask them how to achieve that instead of assuming you know the solution. After reading your comments, I am not sure if posting an EOS event is what you are looking for as that on its own is simple, but seems to not do the trick for you.